# How to fix ImportError: No module named cryptography?

Tags: pip, cryptography, certbot

I want to auto renew certificate via certbot, but not working, got error "ImportError: No module named cryptography"

**# ./certbot-auto --dry-run**

Error: couldn't get currently installed version for /opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/bin/letsencrypt:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/bin/letsencrypt", line 7, in 
    from certbot.main import main
  File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 10, in 
    import josepy as jose
  File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/josepy/**init**.py", line 41, in 
    from josepy.interfaces import JSONDeSerializable
  File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/josepy/interfaces.py", line 7, in 
    from josepy import errors, util
  File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/josepy/util.py", line 7, in 
    import OpenSSL
  File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/**init**.py", line 8, in 
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 12, in 
    from cryptography import x509
**ImportError: No module named cryptography**

I tried to install cryptography, and got this result

**sudo /opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/bin/pip install cryptography**

You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 19.2.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Then I tried this command
**pip install --upgrade pip**

DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-19.2.3-py2.7.egg (19.2.3)

How to get cryptography installed?

Comment: why are you using once ` /opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/bin/pip` and then `pip install --upgrade pip` (which points to `pip` at the global level? use `/opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Successfully installedI got the exact same error message after I ran certbot-auto and it upgraded to the new version.

Here's how I solve this in my case:

```
pip install cryptography 
cd /opt/eff.org/certbot/venv/lib64/python2.7 
mv site-packages site-packages.sav 
ln -s dist-packages/ site-packages
```

It's because the letsencrypt's custom version of python is looking for the package under ***site-packages*** subfolder while it's empty in my case and the package is under ***dist-packages*** subfolder.

*Note: If you see cryptography is successfully installed then no need to run 'pip install --upgrade pip' command and can disregard the warning information.*

Comment: This worked as written for me today on AL 2017.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this same problem when trying to renew my certbot certificate on AWS EC2 instance.  I started by installing cryptography, then getting the virtual environment to look in the right directory for it, then there was another package that it couldn't find, and all the responses from github are that they don't support these AWS instances.  Soooooo, I resorted to this simple idea, and it worked perfectly:

```
cd /opt
sudo rm -R eff.org
cd ~
wget https://dl.eff.org/certbot-auto
chmod a+x certbot-auto
./certbot-auto renew --debug
```

That is, I deleted the old installation, and reinstalled it with the "renew" command.  Worked perfectly.  Your keys aren't stored in the directories that you delete.